# Error: <line> attribute x1: Expected length, "NaN" in react with d3 and webpack

Tags: javascript, reactjs, d3.js, svg, line

I am looping over an array of lines with has various sources and targets for a force directed graph. When the following code executes I see everything fine in the browser but I see numerous errors in the console.

```
      {lines.map((line, index) => (
          // height = 100, width = 100
          <line
            x1={Math.max(75, Math.min(height - 75, line.source.x))}
            y1={Math.max(75, Math.min(width - 75, line.source.y))}
            x2={Math.max(75, Math.min(height - 75, line.target.x))}
            y2={Math.max(75, Math.min(width - 75, line.target.y))}
            key={index}          
          />              
        )}
```

The errors are:

```
Error: <line> attribute x1: Expected length, "NaN"
Error: <line> attribute y1: Expected length, "NaN"
Error: <line> attribute x2: Expected length, "NaN"
Error: <line> attribute y2: Expected length, "NaN"
```

I am unsure what exactly is going on, any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.